# How to Segment text image to its Basic Components like line and curves?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I'm working of OCR Project in C#. I'm thinking about segmenting text image into its basic components like lines, curves, loops and find their orientations so that I can use them for feature extraction and recognition.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

For example: If I've text image of letter 'A' then it must be segmented into three basic components '/', '-' and '\'.

Comment: You could manually create a *template* of all the possible *components*, then, for a given image, you could use [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) (or just simple correlation, since your images seem to be simple) to match all the possible templates and then filter the combination with highest probability/correlation.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach this kind of problem(digit or character recognition) like template matching on various scales(mostly decreasing scales), feature based approach like HOG features which are widely used features for digit and character recognition.

now answer to your question, there are some approaches to detect lines and curves in images.

**Easiest Approch:**

If you have a thresholded image (i.e. binary image), just apply image opening operation with a Line structural element with different orientation like horizontal line for horizontal line segmentation, vertical line for vertical line segmentation or diagonal line for diagonal lines detection, if you are familiar with **MATLAB** you can create different line structures with different orientation and length using "strel()" function and just apply "imopen" operation with a suitable length of line(according to size of your characters).
you have to do some hit and try for length and orientation of the line.

**Little Harder way**

But quite useful way is applying Hough transformation and than you can detect any kind of line and defined curve but for this you have to do little hard work.
Here are some links for papers which are following the same approach:
http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS474/Handouts/HoughTransformPaper.pdf
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/LIB/bandb4_3.pdf

**Harder Way**

Try supervised method using some feature based techniques such as HOG, which are based on orientation of gradients read stuff about it, it may help you.

All the best

Comment: My effort is towards omnifont (font independent) Optical Character Recognition System. The character set is itself large (Devanagari Character Set including conjuncts). Here [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3884.pdf) is the paper I've gone through. And I'm not familiar with **MATLAB**. Is there any alternative to **MATLAB** library in C#?

Comment: hi Niranjan, i have just gone through the link you have mentioned, approach proposed in the paper is pretty much convincing for basic level of character recognition, but as you have large data set then i think it will also have lots of variability corresponds to structure, more robust approach to try these kind of problems is feature based approaches, as i have discussed earlier, i have made a digit classifier using HOG features, and it was a successful attempt, in OpenCV you can find a library for HOG features search for that, or if you know theory or principal of it you can implement it.

Comment: other way is as i have discussed image open operation, it is not MATLAB dependent operation, basically it is dilation after erosion operation. i have also used this approach for vertical and horizontal line detection for a character set. just apply image opening with a mask of e.g 3X3 such as center column have 1 and all other elements as 0 and first erode the binary image and than dilate it; this will give you all vertical lines of the character, similarly you can try for horizontal and diagonal elements, choose size of mask according character size, I think you can give a try to this.